# SoundPool sounds stuttering on KitKat

Tags: android, xamarin, android-4.4-kitkat, soundpool

In a Xamarin Android (not Xamarin Forms) application on KitKat (API 19), using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I'm having trouble with playback of sounds from a `SoundPool`. Sometimes my sound plays fine. Other times it stutters.

Weirdest of all, on rare occasion, playback fails completely with a warning in the debug log like:

```
W/SoundPool(30751):   sample 2 not READY
```

This is despite the fact that I have absolutely positively waited for the sample to be loaded before trying to play it, and despite the **same sample ID** playing just fine immediately **before and after** the "sample X not READY" failure.

The TL;dr version of the code:

```
var Pool = new SoundPool(6, Stream.Music, 0);
var ToneID = await Pool.LoadAsync(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.tone, 1);
beepButton.Click += (sender, e) => Pool.Play(ToneID, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1, 0, 1.0F);
```

The `Resource.Raw.tone` is little-endian 16-bit PCM mono audio with a sample rate of 44100Hz and a Microsoft "WAV" header. It is a 0.25s 440Hz sine wave created using Audacity 2.1.3.

I know all about `SoundPool.Builder`. It was introduced in API 21. I'm targeting API 19.

The actual code disables the button for 500ms after each press, so there's no chance I'm trying to play the sample more than once concurrently. Indeed, I can reproduce the problem with individual presses some tens of seconds apart.

Things I have tried without success:

- using smaller or larger `maxStreams` (first arg) values when calling the `SoundPool` ctor
- using different `Android.Media.Stream` enumeration values for `streamType` (second arg) when calling the `SoundPool` ctor
- using different `srcQuality` (third arg) values when calling the `SoundPool` ctor (despite the Android docco saying it does nothing and to always use zero)
- using different `priority` (third arg) values when calling the `SoundPool.Load()` instance method
- using sub-unity volume arguments (like `0.99F`) when calling the `SoundPool.Play()` instance method
- using different `priority` (fourth arg) values when calling the `SoundPool.Play()` instance mehtod
- using different file formats (MP3, OggVorbis) for my sound resource

Here is [a .zip file](http://mythopoeic.org/misc-files/SoundTest.zip) containing my entire ready-to-build application. This is essentially just the template app except for the `MainActivity.cs`.

What the app should do: beep each time you press the (one and only) button on the UI. It will probably do just that the first dozen presses or so. But then you'll hear "BaBeep" or "BeeeeBip" or "Bee<pause>beep" or silence.

FWIW, the same resource plays back just fine every time using `MediaPlayer`.

(Edited to link a much-simplified and cleaned-up .zip file example.)

Comment: When you press the button, you want it play the `tone` several times and each time has a time interval?

Comment: No, I just want to play `tone` once for each button press. I also disallow any more button presses for a period of time, just so nobody wonders "did it sound weird because my finger bounced on the button?"

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem that it sound "stutters", in which situation you will have this problem?

Comment: To reproduce: Build the application in the .zip file linked above. Run it. Press the "Beep" button. It will usually work fine, but about 1 time in 20 the beep will be wrong or missing. I'm starting to suspect this may be platform-dependent; I'm running on a Symbol TC75 with Android 4.4.3.

Comment: Another data point: The same test program works flawlessly on a Symbol TC75 with Android Lollipop (5.1.1).

Comment: I have test your project with one hundred time, it works perfectly, I'm running on M6 with Android 7.0.